# Java - best way to detect NPE at compile time when not allowed to use @NotNull or @Nullable annotations

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I used to use lots of `@NotNull/@Nullable` annotations to enable IDE to help me find out potential `NPE` at compile time. However, my new team doesn't allow any use of `@NotNull/@Nullable` annotations, and nor are custom annotations like those allowed. As a result, I become much more likely to write bugs caused by `NPE` than before.

I have tried several solutions:

1. Use `Optional<T>` in java 8. However, this is not doing well for every case. It's usually not recommended to use `Optional<T>` as the type of fields or arguments. It's also very frustrating that `Optional<T>` instance itself could be `null`. Also, it's difficult to operate control flows inside lambda expressions when calling `ifPresent(obj->...)`(it's easier in Java 9). And using too many `Optional<T>`s makes the code a little verbose.**（UPDATE: Unfortunately, `Optional<T>` is also banned from using now)**
2. Make IDE treat every unannotated instance as `@Nullable`. This solution does help me find out some potential bugs, however, IDE would suggest me to check almost every method invocation, which is really annoying, since many methods are designed intentionally not returning `null`.
3. Check every method invocations. This is a viable solution, however it has a severe influence that the possibility of being `null` would be passed everywhere through method invocations. Under such circumstances, every argument of a method is possible to be `null`, and when an argument is checked for nullity, the method would usually return a `null` continuously. Finally, every method is "infected" with the possibility of receiving `null` arguments and returning `null`.
4. Call `Objects.requireNonNull()` to prevent the problem aforementioned. It slightly reduces the pain of checking `null` everywhere. However, it provides no guarantee that the caller won't pass a `null` to the cases when `null` is not allowed. And once `null` is passed, the runtime `NPE` thrown is much more likely to ruin your application.
5. Switch to kotlin. Of course, it's not allowed:)

Is there other suggestions about detecting NPE at compile time (and save my job)? **I think a solution to this problem could be widely used, not only helping myself, since not all teams allow usage of `@NotNull/@Nullable` annotations and `Optional<T>`s.**

Comment: That was one good way. Should really ask your team to follow what you were practicing.

Comment: If NPEs are a big issue to the point where you've got to use annotations and IDE help to avoid them, then it kind of seems like the design isn't quite the best implementation and may need to be rethought.

Comment: @j.seashell I agree. But I must work together with other developers and plenty of old badly designed code which I am not authorized to modify. Almost every method I call would get a nullable result, and then it starts "infecting" other code.

Comment: @nullpointer however I failed to persuade my leader, who is in fact a perfectionist on code style.

Comment: You are asking kind of an impossible to answer question. If your code-style (whoever is controlling this) does not allow anything to modify and does not allow any annotations, there is no way that the IDE can help you (because how should it know). If you just want to prevent the NPE from happing, write for each method you implement a test-method passing in `null` values. Expect an error if you expect it otherwise fix the implementation and detect your problem early.

Comment: Don't you think to use `SonarQube`? It has `Possible NPE` rules to check the code.

Comment: @Phillip Re: 'there is no way that the IDE can help you'...Eclipse has a plugin for FindBugs, and also supports a compiler option to report 'Potential null pointer access' (though it is turned off by default).

Comment: I doubt you'll want to do this, but suggest anyway that you look for a new team. A "perfectionist on code style" who prohibits known best practices is likely to create a very unpleasant work environment.

Comment: @Gene yes...it's quite unpleasant especially during code review and I have to 'guess' what style the reviewer likes

Comment: It's really a crime that  didn't require code to declare whether variables were nullable from its inception and refuse to compile any unchecked derefencing, as well as allowing unchecked casts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not a definitive answer but a few way to explore:

- Tools like [findBug](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/), [PMD](https://pmd.github.io/) , [Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/) ... are quite good at this exercice.
- Check the reason why you cannot use the annotation in your team. Maybe you can make your team change its mind? (There might be a good reason too.)
- Eclipse IDE is reasonnably good at this exercice. Did you try the options in 'Windows > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Null analysis'?
- Unit testing. Cover the 'should-not-happen' situation in a few test cases. Code coverage tools (like [JaCoCo](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/)) might be helpfull as wel.
- Defensive programming (plain 'if' statement, assertions ...)
- A mix of the previous items

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

You did not say what IDE you are using but Eclipse and Intellij support external annotations. With them, you can still annotate your code locally and have the IDE provide null analysis.

[Intellij Documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/external-annotations.html)
[Eclipse Documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_external_null_annotations.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably find a way to use `Optional<T>` that suits your cases.

Let's say you have to write a method `U doStuff(T param)`, and that `param` is given to your code by some library from other person and it may be null.

Inside the body of the method `doStuff`you can do

```
return Optional.ofNullable(param)
       .map(notNullParam -> doThing(notNullParam))
       .orElse(null);
```

This way, you are sure that your `Optional`itself is not null, people can still  use your API with parameters that are null, and you return null when it makes sense for them.

Comment: Using `Optional` could solve part of the problem, however, the problem of "passing null from one place to another" would become "passing optional from one place to another".

Comment: With the design I proposed, you get a null and you return a null, but you are ensured to not throw NPE in the body of the method (which is supposed to be your code). Other people can handle null values any way they want elsewhere in the code, but your code will not crash. (You do not return or pass around Optional).

Comment: UPDATE NOW: `Optional` is totally banned now.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend checking out **SonarLint** which is a very nice tool to detect all kind of bugs and errors including **NPE**.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do - is come up with a good API design and specify which of the layers are allowed to return null and which not.

In general, you should always try to return something else rather than null - empty collection, an object representing `not-found`.

So you should check for nulls manually where the return could make sense to be null. Otherwise, just convene to not return null and just don't check.

You can also introduce some utility methods to check for null/empty collections:

`Check.isEmpty()` would return true if collection is null or is not null but is empty and so on...

You could also use the [null-object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)

Comment: What you describe is exactly the idea of `Optional<T>`.  You'd return an optional result in the cases you describe, and `val.isPresent()` is just the logical reverse of your suggested `isEmpty()`.

Comment: I described at least 4 different approaches. `Optional` might not be available to him

Answer (score 0):

I can relate your problem to my use cases as well. In those cases feel free to suggest code coverage tools.

- **JaCoCo** is very handy. If you use IntelliJ, inbuilt Jacoco/IJ's code coverage clearly gives you the violations and possible NPE
- **Unit tests** to support your domain wise non-nullable object scenarios

After all, **NPE** is still either *design based/programmer based fault*. Keep your code well tested and proper checks to avoid NPE and throw custom exceptions or `IllegalArgumentException` if your service expects a valid value.